# Center aligning dynamic slides within carousel (BXSlider)

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

I am struggling to get the slides to center align within the wrapper. My carousel can have a dynamic number of slides and therefore may not fill the width of the wrapper. They are aligned left by default but I need them center aligned. Can anyone help?

I have created a JSFiddle to display my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/ysuf1u1p/2/

```
.bxslider-inner {
    display: inline-block;
    float:none !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.bx-wrapper {
    max-width: 460px!important;
    text-align:center;
}

<ul class="bxslider">
  <li class="bxslider-inner"><div style="width:80px; height:80px; background:#CCC; padding:5px;">1</div></li>
 <li class="bxslider-inner"><div style="width:80px; height:80px; background:#F5F5F5; padding:5px;">2</div></li>
    <li class="bxslider-inner"><div style="width:80px; height:80px; background:#F5F5F5; padding:5px;">3</div></li>
</ul>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'horizontal',
    speed: 500,
    slideMargin:10,
    infiniteLoop: false,
    pager: false,
    controls: true,
    slideWidth: 80,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 5,
    moveSlides: 1       
      });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check updated fiddle <kbd>[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/ysuf1u1p/3/)</kbd>

```
$(".bxslider").each(function(){
    var nextDisabled = $(this).parents(".bx-wrapper:eq(0)").find(".bx-next").hasClass('disabled');
    var prevDisabled = $(this).parents(".bx-wrapper:eq(0)").find(".bx-prev").hasClass('disabled');
    if(nextDisabled && prevDisabled)
  {
    $(this).css("display","inline");
  }
});
```

Comment: Did I miss something? The slides are not centered. What exactly does your code do?

Comment: @zer00ne Its center aligned as per OP wants. You can check jsfiddle in answer.

Comment: It isn't centered the far right box is smaller than the rest of the boxes. Can you please explain your code? What is it doing? Have you seen my demo? The boxes are all identical in dimension hence centered within the wrapper. I'd like to know why I got a downvote so I may rectify the problem, sir.

Comment: @zer00ne as per OP's fiddle its bottom second BxSlider is not center aligned. So I have resolved it by adding style by jquery. Problem only occurs if slider content is smaller than visible box wrapper.

Comment: @zer00ne I have added new bx slider in your fiddle as per OP's fiddle with three li then its not working. Its showing left aligned.

Comment: Would not use OP's bxSlider, it is flawed, which is the whole point. bxSlider or just about any slider for that matter is affected (usually adversely) by arbitrary padding, margins, etc. I'll rescind my downvote since you have a better understanding of OPs *needs* such as it is.

Comment: Hi, This solution works great for me although its breaks in IE.  None of the slides show at all in IE!  The weird thing is, I discovered if I press the ALT key they show.  This is really bizarre.  Any idea how I can get this working for IE?  Many thanks in advance.